# An yet another multiple IF statement in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm having a bit of a pickle constructing this multiple IF statement.
This is what I need (pseudo-code):

**IF** C7<=150000 **THEN** C7*G8 **OR**

**IF** C7=>175000 **AND** C7=>500000 **THEN** C7*G9 **OR**

**IF** C7=>525000 **THEN** C7*G10

... all in one statement. The final result must also have a € (euro symbol) to the right (being as currency doesn't seem to add the character).

Pedro

Comment: What prevents you from creating a formula out of it? You're almost there. The € symbol can be created by formatting the cell as Currency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, you had to use **AND** when you want to know if value falls within specific range.

```
=IF(C7<=150000;C7*G8;IF(AND(C7>=175000;C7<=500000);C7*G9;IF(C7>=525000;C7*G10;"Value out of Range")))&" €"
```